# How to divide a list of arrays into into subarrays?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list 'a' with following element values. In my code, I created a list :

```
a=[]
b=np.zeros(3)
c=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    b[0]=i+1
    b[1]=i+2
    b[2]=i+3
    c.append(deepcopy(b))
a.append(c)
c=[]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[array([1., 2., 3.]), array([2., 3., 4.]), array([3., 4., 5.]), array([4., 5., 6.])]]
```

Above list is example like I get in my data

I tried to make array

```
b=np.array(a)

array([[[1., 2., 3.],
    [2., 3., 4.],
    [3., 4., 5.],
    [4., 5., 6.]]])
b.shape
(1,4,3)
```

But I want to make b of shape (4,1,3) which gives following output:
So that when I access

```
b[0] gives [1,2,3]
b[1] gives [2,3,4]
b[2] gives [3,4,5]
b[3] gives [4,5,6]
```

Comment: b is of shape (1,4,3) . Here b[0] gives all data of a list. For my data processing, at first i Need to reshape b as b[0] gives [1,2,3] , b[1] gives [2,3,4] @JGFMK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in function for this:
b = np.vstack(a)

**EDITED**

After using np.vstack(a)

```
b=b.reshape(4,3,1)
```

This gives required result

```
b[0]- > [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This is a nice and easy approach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but you should be able to get the result as:

```
b = np.array(a[0])

print(b[0]) # [1. 2. 3.]
print(b[1]) # [2. 3. 4.]
print(b[2]) # [3. 4. 5.]
print(b[3]) # [4. 5. 6.]
```

---

To preserve 3D array:

```
np.array([a[0]]).reshape(4,1,3)

print(b[0]) #=> [[1. 2. 3.]]
print(b[1]) #=> [[2. 3. 4.]]
print(b[2]) #=> [[3. 4. 5.]]
print(b[3]) #=> [[4. 5. 6.]]
```

Comment: This destroys 3D array . I need to maintain 3 D array which is required in later part of my data processing. Doing np.vstack(a) changes shape to 2D array. I need b.shape as (4,3,1) so that I can call b[:,0,2]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
Use @orli answer it's easier to type!

Using basic Python 3.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
a=[]
b=np.zeros(3)
c=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    b[0]=i+1
    b[1]=i+2
    b[2]=i+3
    c.append(deepcopy(b))
a.append(c)
res = []
for r in a:
    for c in r:
        rw = []
        for e in c.tolist():
            rw.append(e)
        res.append(rw)
print(res)
```

Yields:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
```

Comment: np.vstack(a) solved my problem partially . However this also works

Comment: Ah - right. Have just tried that too. Cool the other way is far easier ;-)